# How to get String Value as Var

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to use PHP string value as Var. how to do it?
I get value from database as

```
$timn = $db->fetchVal("select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ts) AS ts from users where id = ?", [$id]);
```

and use it in my javascript as

```
var directTime =  $timn;
```

$timn has a value say 12500, if i write

```
  var directTime =  12500;
```

then no issue

any solution?

Comment: from php to js how are you passing data?

Comment: try this `var directTime =  12500.toString()`
 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Method 1

```
var directTime = <?=($timn)?>;
```

### Method 2

Try putting it in a hidden div:

```
<div style="display:none" id="time"><?=($timn)?></div>
```

Then get its value in your script:

```
var directTime = $("#time").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    var directTime =  '<?php echo $timn; ?>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript code write below

```
var directTime =  <?php echo $timn; ?>;
```